# Conversion of Multiple ascii code to char

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that convert `string to ascii code` (e.g `string = "system"` the value of string in `ascii = "115 121 115  116 101 109"`) and what i need is a way to convert the `ascii into char. Do i need to use loop to filter the converted ascii ? I need your suggestion what is the best way to convert it

Comment: Why don't you alter the mentioned function to return a `char` array instead of a string, and later you can join the array if you want to represent the whole thing as a string.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is one that checks your assumptions. You say the string contains ASCII bytes. So if someone slips in a byte that cannot be ASCII, you should be told. It does appear that someone slipped in an unexpected space, but that can be ignored.

```
Imports System.Linq
'…

Dim asciiEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("US-ASCII", 
    EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback, 
    DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback)

Dim ascii = "115 121 115  116 101 109"
Dim asciiBytes = ascii.Split( { " "c }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) _
    .Select(Function (s) Byte.Parse(s)) _
    .ToArray()
Dim s = asciiEncoding.GetString(asciiBytes)
```

Other ways might not catch invalid data.

Some ways automagically convert from the ASCII character set to the Unicode character set, which is valid when the data is, in fact, ASCII but at least deserves a comment about the conversion and that the data is trusted to be ASCII.

Speaking of whether the data is ASCII or not, *there is no text but encoded text.* When you read text, you have to use the encoding it was written with. The only way to know is for the writer to make it known.

Comment: Yeah, character encoding is a rabbit hole that is hard to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is:

First split the string using `string.split(' ');`

And then convert each split string to char like this:

```
foreach(string word in SplitedWords)
{
   Convert.ToChar(int.Parse(word));
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer even its in C#. And I get the output that i really want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is built-in. You can treat a `String` as an array of `Char`.

```
Dim s As String = "system"
Console.WriteLine(s(4) & " = ASCII " & Asc(s(4))) 'output: e = ASCII 101    
Console.ReadKey()
```

You can use the `Asc()` function to get the ASCII value of the character, but be aware that `String`s and `Char`s are actually Unicode, not ASCII. Depending on encoding, you might find that one character is more than one byte.

FOR THE NITPICKERS: When you treat a `String` as an array of `Char`, the compiler boxes the `String`, so it is less efficient that having a true `Char` array.

Comment: I dont get  it. Can you please explain further? Because what i need is to convert the value of ascii where the data type is in string

Comment: `Asc` probably doesn't do what you think it does. But, if all of the `Char`s in the string represent Unicode codepoints in the [C0 and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block, you will get the same results. Even so, it's best to avoid anything to do with the user's/system's/thread's current default ANSI code page, unless that is exactly what the requirements call for. (This applies since VB4.)